# How to change the stroke width of a shape rectangle programmatically

Tags: android, drawable, shapes, stroke

How can I change the stroke width of a rectangle button when I press the button?

I have created a xml file in drawable folder for my custom button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="9dp"/>
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:centerX="9%"
        android:centerColor="#84edb2"
        android:startColor="#07e7cb"
        android:endColor="#b0ede3"
        android:type="linear"
        />
    <size
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="30dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp" // I want to change this programmatically.
        android:color="#2f7E87"
        />
</shape>
```

Below is my java code.
I want to change the button's stroke width when I press the button.

```
public static void buttonEffect(View button){
    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        ShapeDrawable circle = new ShapeDrawable( new OvalShape() );


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    Button view = (Button) v;
                    int col = Color.parseColor("#40E0D0");
                    view.getBackground().setColorFilter(col, PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN);
                    v.invalidate();

                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Your action here on button click
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                    Button view = (Button) v;
                    view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    view.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try below solution, It'll help you to solve your problem hopefully.

[Here is a screenshot, Have a look](http://prnt.sc/f2773t)

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.red_500),
        ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.red_500), ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.red_500)});
gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
gd.setStroke((int)0.5, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black));
gd.setCornerRadius(8f);
gd.setBounds(2, 2, 2, 2);
btnCreateUser.setBackground(gd);
```

*When you click your button, set width of stroke in this line according to your requirement, So that you don't have to use xml anymore*

```
i.e: gd.setStroke((int)1, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black));
i.e: gd.setStroke((int)3, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think solution is :
 + Create two shape drawable with difference size stroke.
 + When touch into button, just change background to other drawable like you done.

Comment: i am new to android can you show me how to do that i don't know that

Answer (score 1):

It is based on @Dương Nguyễn Văn answer.

You have a button with the default stroke width of 2dp. Now you want its stroke width to change to 4dp when you press it.
So, you create two drawable files: **bg_button_2.xml (stroke width = 2dp)**, and **bg_button_4.xml (stroke width = 4dp).**

Now you can change its background programmatically.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View view) {
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_button_4);
      }
});
```